# Hightcharts label alignment

Tags: highcharts

I am using a highchart 3d column series and facing issues with label alignment with zAxis categories

The fiddle that works well is here with plotOptions like

```
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        groupZPadding: 10,
        depth: 100, /* with this depth the labels align well */
        groupPadding: 0,
        grouping: false,
      }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54odsvy0/

When I decrease the `series.depth` in the `plotOptions` to 50, the labels go out of sync and do not get aligned with the columns on zAxis

http://jsfiddle.net/v5mLoa0g/

```
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        groupZPadding: 10,
        depth: 50, /* with this depth the labels do not align */
        groupPadding: 0,
        grouping: false,
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can try to play around `chart.depth`, i.e. set it to 350 http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tk6p915d/ to align it, but in general, Highcharts doesn't support z coordinates for column series. You can propose this idea as a future request: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: This is exactly what I figured out this morning  by multiple experiments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to align the column depths with the chart depths

Chart depth = (Depth of each column * number of columns) + Total Z padding from spaces between columns

For instance, since I had the column depth to 50 and ZPadding to 10

chart.options3d.depth = (50 * 5) + (10 * (5-1))
= 250 + 40 = 290

Comment: Fiddle with update chartdepth
http://jsfiddle.net/yu4w58mp/